# When is a commitment fulfilled on Area 51?

Tags: support, area-51, beta-phase, commitment, commitment-fulfillment

I commited to [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352/not-programming-related), now the site is in public beta, and I have been active in the site by posting 4 questions and 18 answers.

But my commitment is still not listed as fulfilled, as my commitment on [GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) is.

When is my commitment fulfulled?

Comment: In best Yoda voice: I cannot teach him. The boy has no patience.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It takes about 24 hours for the commitment fulfillment task to run (it's daily). Give it some time.