# How to "follow through" on an area51 proposal

Tags: support, area-51, beta-phase

Can someone explain what it means to "follow through" on an Area51 proposal? It's not clear to me from the Area51 FAQ.

I am committed to three proposals-- one of them is in beta. I have participated by voting and answering questions, yet on Area51 it tells me I cannot commit to another proposal because I have not "followed through" yet. (I haven't found another proposal I want to commit to yet, but I'm curious). Do I need a certain amount of rep on the new beta site?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you weren't active enough during the private beta, you will need to [post at least 10 questions or answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57876/commitment-fulfilled-seems-to-act-erratic-on-area-51/57878#57878) to fulfill your commitment.  Once you do that, you can commit to another proposal.

The threshold is lower if you are very active during the private beta, though note that the earliest you can get credit for a fulfilled commitment is [the second day of the public beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq#commitment).

Your commitment will also expire after [the public beta ends](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65984/what-does-it-take-for-a-commitment-to-count-as-fulfilled/65993#65993) or [after the site has been in beta for six months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123456/160551) (whichever comes first).

Once you meet the requirements, it might take [a day before your commitment is marked as fulfilled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63973/when-is-a-commitment-fulfilled-on-area-51/63974#63974).

Comment: Is this written anywhere? Can someone put it in the Area51 FAQ? I think it would be useful...

Comment: @Jeff Search discuss.area51, you'll see it. The FAQ says "asking and answering a few questions", it should probably be more specific.  Troyen, there's no commitment expiration that I know of; I've been committed to Code Golf without fulfillment for more than 3 months.

Comment: @Matthew I thought otherwise [based on this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65984/what-does-it-take-for-a-commitment-to-count-as-fulfilled/65993#65993) but I haven't personally tried.

Comment: @Matthew I guess I may have misread that post.  It might not be timed but just the end of the beta stage for that site.

Comment: @Troyen I think Jeff's wording is wrong, actually -- the *ideal* beta is 90 days, but some like Code Golf's are much longer.

Comment: @Matthew Yeah, based on the date (Sep '10) it was probably when most sites graduated in 90 days.  Since then the beta phase has elongated, but the commitment logic may not have changed.  Thus, the quickest way is to figure out some combination of questions/answers to get to ten.

Comment: this isn't really correct; it's less if you do it during the private beta.

Comment: if you post "enough" during the private beta, you indeed will fulfill the commitment immediately after the site goes to public beta. If you don't, you have to post more. So to fulfill your commitment, either do the work during the private beta, or do *even more* work later.